# Mapping in Dozer Mapper fails

Tags: spring, dozer

I am using Dozer mapper in Spring boot. If I map Data from Entity to EntityDTO, then work of dozer maper is to copy the data from entity class to EntityDTO and it does the same in case of primitives. But suppose I have a class like this

```
Class Entity{
public EntityChild entityChild; //leaving getter and setter here. 
}
```

and DTO with name EntityDTO

```
Class EntityDTO{
public EntityChildDTO entityChildDTOs; //leaving getter and setter here. 
}
```

then it doesn't map the data from entityChild to entityChildDTOs, Can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute names have to be the same for Dozer to automatically map it. So `EntityDTO`'s attribute has to be named `entityChild` too, for example.

Comment: Yes I did that only, but when I do that thing, it changes the type of the attribute, for example if I am mapping the data of entityChildDTO to entityChild having the same attribute name, then type of entityChild changes to entityChildDTO. This is the problem I am facing

Answer (score 0):

Part of mapping for this two entities, based on the [official manual](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html):

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>Entity</class-a>
  <class-b>EntityDTO</class-b>

  <field>
    <!-- this is the same for all sub classes -->
    <a>entityChild</a> 
    <b>entityChildDTOs</b>
  </field>
</mapping>
<!--Add mapping for EntityChild and EntityChildDTO here-->
```

You task is very basic and it definitely works in Dozer.